# Power Automate - Cloud Flow - Using xpath for parent node attributes

Tags: xpath, power-automate

1. A RESTful API call returns the XML noted below.
2. I need to loop through various steps for each ShowSurveyAnswerKey.  So in this case, 8 of them.  Got that working with an "Apply to each" step expression of:

```
xpath(xml(body('HTTP_Get')),'//ShowSurveyAnswer')
```

3. In that "Apply to each", need to know values of ShowSurveyKey, ShowSurveyQuestionKey and ShowSurveyAnswerKey.  The only one I can get working is ShowSurveyAnswerKey, which I happen to be testing with an action "Compose" with expression of:

```
xpath(item(),'string(/ShowSurveyAnswer/@ShowSurveyAnswerKey)')
```

**So really, I can't figure out the parent or ancestor or ../ within Power Automate Compose Expression within the "Apply to each".**

All help much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Show ShowKey="123" >
    <ShowSurveys>
        <ShowSurvey ShowSurveyKey="230151" >
            <SurveyQuestions>
                <SurveyQuestion ShowSurveyQuestionKey="842125" >
                    <SurveyAnswers>
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3316719" />
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3316720" />
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3316721" />
                    </SurveyAnswers>
                </SurveyQuestion>
            </SurveyQuestions>
        </ShowSurvey>
        <ShowSurvey ShowSurveyKey="217418" >
            <SurveyQuestions>
                <SurveyQuestion ShowSurveyQuestionKey="808668" >
                    <SurveyAnswers>
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3192170" />
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3192174" />
                    </SurveyAnswers>
                </SurveyQuestion>
                <SurveyQuestion ShowSurveyQuestionKey="808669" >
                    <SurveyAnswers>
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3192175" />
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3192176" />
                        <ShowSurveyAnswer ShowSurveyAnswerKey="3192177" />
                    </SurveyAnswers>
                </SurveyQuestion>
            </SurveyQuestions>
        </ShowSurvey>
    </ShowSurveys>
</Show>
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `/ShowSurveyAnswer/ancestor::*/@ShowSurveyQuestionKey` or `/ShowSurveyAnswer/ancestor::*/@ShowSurveyKey ` ?

Comment: Thanks - just did and unfortunately, both returned output "".
Such as:

xpath(item(),'string(/ShowSurveyAnswer/ancestor::*/@ShowSurveyQuestionKey)')

and the tried with parent as:
xpath(item(),'string(/ShowSurveyAnswer/parent::*/@ShowSurveyQuestionKey)')

Got same "" output.  So strange.  I can get it to work with 3x nested Apply to Each, but prefer not for performance & effort.